# Mocking third-party function inside class method

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, patch, fixtures

This is probably a trivial issue, but I can't get a proper solution and I don't understand how to fix it. I simplified the problem, so I have two files `my_module.py` and `test_module.py` at the same localization.

```py
import numpy as _np


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.attribute = 1
        self.method()

    def method(self) -> None:
        arr = _np.arange(9).reshape(-1, 3)
        self.attribute = 2
```

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

import pytest

from my_module import MyClass


@pytest.fixture
def init_mock():
    with patch.object(MyClass, '__init__', return_value=None) as init:
        yield init


@pytest.fixture
def method_mock():
    with patch.object(MyClass, 'method') as method:
        yield method


@pytest.fixture
def my_class_init_mock(init_mock):
    yield MyClass()


@pytest.fixture
def my_class_method_mock(method_mock):
    yield MyClass()


def test_init(my_class_method_mock):
    assert my_class_method_mock.attribute == 1


def test_method(my_class_init_mock):
    my_class_init_mock.method()
    assert my_class_init_mock.attribute == 2
```

All two tests passed. Moreover, I need to check whether `_np.arange(9).reshape` was called once with `-1, 3` arguments. I found that I should refer directly to `numpy` from `my_module.py`. I've tried to add `@patch('my_module._np')` above the last test. I also tried to pass the fixture of the module to the fixture of `my_class_method_mock`. Unfortunately, I'm not able to call this mock when I trigger `.method()` function. How to create a connection between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved defining a fixture of `_np` and checking whether this mock was called:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def numpy_mock():
    with patch('my_module._np') as numpy:
        yield numpy

...

def test_method(my_class_init_mock, numpy_mock):
    my_class_init_mock.method()
    numpy_mock.arange.assert_called_once_with(9)
    numpy_mock.arange().reshape.assert_called_once_with(-1, 3)
    assert my_class_init_mock.attribute == 2
```

Note that we can assert each piece of a method chaining.